# What is the result of ( : , : , 0 ) in a 4D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the result of a 4D array when I ask ( : , : , 0 ) ?

```
a=np.random.randint(1,10,size=(3,3,3,3))

a[: , :, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

`a[:, :, 0]` is same as `a[:, :, 0, :]`. because `numpy` starts indexing from the left side (outermost dimension). Hence any index you leave out will result in the inner dimensions, getting selected automatically.

You can verify this by `a[:, :, 0] == a[:, :, 0, :]` which will return an array of all True with shape `(3,3,3)`.